# pycurl doesn't import after update python to 2.7

Tags: python, pycurl

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and had python 2.6 before. pycurl worked fine.

after I updated my python to 2.7, pycurl doesn't import

```
>>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pycurl
```

I tried to re-install python using

```
sudo apt-get install python-pycurl
```

It told me pycurl was already in the newest version

How do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

- Download the latest version from http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/
- Extract the tar.gz that you downloaded
- `cd` to the extracted directory
- Read the `INSTALL` file and do what it says

It should probably look something like this:

```
wget http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
cd pycurl-7.19.0
sudo python2.7 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo pip install pycurl` instead. Also, make sure that `/usr/bin/python` points to version 2.7.